# Is it possible to use a "front controller" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dispatcher, front-controller

In Spring MVC a Dispatcher servlet is used as a "front controller" to handle all of the application requests and route them appropriately.

Is it possible to use such an approach in Rails or is it required to write a separate controller for each type of action without having a "traffic cop" (front controller) directing the flow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

checkout the rails cast on catchall routes, I *think* this is what you are after:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/46-catch-all-route

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Merb is more what you're after if you want more fine grained control over routing.